# API calls organization in Ionic (Angular) application

Tags: javascript, api, angular-2+

I'm doing a prototype of server API calls in my Ionic (Angular) application. I'm considering this use case:

```
@IonicPage({/* */})
@Component({/* */})
export class SomePage {
  constructor(private api: Api) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.user.getList();
  }
}
```

To achieve this I have something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Api {
  constructor(
    public user: UserApi,
    public event: EventApi,
    public search: SearchApi
  ) {

  }
}

@Injectable()
export class UserApi extends BaseApi {
  private static readonly ENDPOINT: string = "user/";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    super(UserApi.ENDPOINT);
  }

  getList() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}

export class BaseApi {
  private host: string = "https://my-site.com/api/";
  protected url: string;

  constructor(endpoint: string) {
    this.url = this.host + endpoint;
  }
}
```

Next purposes:

- Separate `API Service` from others `Servicies`
- Split one `API Service` to little parts where each one works with single essence

And I have a few questions about my approach:

- Are there any pitfalls in this approach?
- Is this a "good" approach to organize API calls? What can I improve or do in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is already pretty good.

What I would do to improve your code is the following:

- Use a config/constants.ts file for your constants.
- Generate two providers (using `ionic g provider <providername>`).
- In the first provider put all the route related code (I always call it server-communication.ts).
- In the second provider put all the logic (I always call it app-data.ts).
- Import the second provider in all the pages where it is needed.

Here is short example:

#### constants.ts:

```
/*
 * SERVER
 */
export const AUTH = "Authorization",
  TOKEN_PREFIX = "Token ",
  SERVER_ADDRESS = "https://myserver.com/api/";
/*
 * ROUTES
 */
export const ROUTE_LOGIN = "login/",
  ROUTE_FACEBOOK = "social/facebook/",
  ROUTE_REGISTER = "register/";
// Go on with all the other constants you might need.
```

#### server-communication.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import {
  SERVER_ADDRESS,
  TOKEN_PREFIX,
  ROUTE_LOGIN,
  ROUTE_FACEBOOK,
  ROUTE_REGISTER
} from "../../config/constants";

@Injectable()
export class ServerCommunicationProvider {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

authenticate(credentials) {
    return this.http
      .post(SERVER_ADDRESS + ROUTE_LOGIN, credentials)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  registerUser(credentials) {
    return this.http
      .post(SERVER_ADDRESS + ROUTE_REGISTER, credentials)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  // Go on with your other routes.

  // If you need to specify more data about the request do it like this:
  getObject(objectID: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get(SERVER_ADDRESS + ROUTE_OBJECT + objectId, this.getHttpHeader())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            resolve(data.json());
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          }
        );
    });
  }

  //Getting the correct format for the authorization header
  getHttpHeader(): RequestOptions {
    return new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: TOKEN_PREFIX + this.storageProv.userToken,
        "content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      })
    });
  }
```

And then utilize those appdata.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ServerCommunicationProvider } from "../server-communication/server-communication";

@Injectable()
export class AppDataProvider {
  constructor(
    private serverProv: ServerCommunicationProvider
  ) {}

login(email: string, password: string): void {
    this.loadingProv.authLoading();
    let credentials = {
      username: email,
      password: password
    };
    this.serverProv.authenticate(credentials).subscribe(
      res => {
      // Your login logic here
      },
      err => {
      // What happens when user can't log in here.
      }
    );
  }
  // More functions with logic for your routes.
```